# I want to get a list of the games "Ryan" has rented that are from consoles made in 2004

Tags: mysql

My query is:

```
"SELECT GameTitle,YearDev From GameRental, Console WHERE GameRental.RentedBy= 
"Ryan" AND EXISTS (SELECT GameTitle, YearDev FROM Console WHERE 
Console.YearDev="2004");
```

This just lists the one game that fulfills that query, as expected, but then lists all the development years of all the consoles. How is this properly done? I need to use a subquery.

Comment: Why are you saying you "need to use a subquery" if I may ask?  Do you need the list of all titles released in 2004 or is that just a means to an end of the parent query? If you could eloborate we can help you better.  Otherwise I'd suggest replacing everything after "AND" with Console.YearDev="2004"

Comment: @Grim Coder It's an assignment where I have to use a subquery as one of my queries.

Comment: This just returns an error because of the interpretation of double quotes. Can we see the actual query?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT g.GameTitle, c.YearDev
  FROM GameRental g
     JOIN Console c
        ON g.console_id = c.id -- or some other key
WHERE c.YearDev="2004"
  AND g.renter = "Ryan";
```

You need to join your games on the console that they were made for.

Comment: For this query, I need to form it into a subquery. It is part of the assignment.

Comment: @user2824852 SELECT * FROM(your query)x

Answer (score 0):

Carson's code will work, but if you need to use a sub-query all you have to do is supplement your EXISTS in his query:

```
SELECT g.GameTitle, c.YearDev
  FROM GameRental g
    JOIN Console c
      ON g.console_id = c.id  -- This is the foreign key or how you'll link the tables
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM Console WHERE YearDev = "2004" )
  AND g.renter = "Ryan";
```

Notice the table aliases of 'g' and 'c'. They will help you be explicit when determining which tables to pull columns from should the tables contain similarly named columns.

Since this is an assignment I'd suggest some further study on joins and sub-queries. Here's a helpful link on the sub-queries:

[Sub-Queries](https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-server-21-using-subqueries-in-the-where-clause/)